# How do I convert a jquery element to a typescript instance?

Tags: jquery, typescript, instance

I have in TypeScript an object named DataTable, with several methods, such as 'refresh'

This DataTable is built on the page like this

```
<table class='DataTable'>...</table>
```

Now, I have need to grab the `table` from code and call the refresh method on it

I can easily access the **element**, but how do i cast it to its **instance**?

How can this be accomplished?

Many thanks!

Comment: I answered the question but I assumed that when you refer to a typescript "element" you are referring to a Typescript object or, even better, to the instance of a typescript class

Comment: correct. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

technically the only way to refer to the instance of the Typescript object is to save it in a variable when you first create it and use it later to call its methods

something like:

```
const table = // your table istance

.... later on you code

table.refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks. but i have many such elements on the page. its only when someone clicks an arbitrary button on the page, do i have to search up the corret datatable, "convert" it to the datatable object, and then invoke the refresh method. any ideas?

Comment: mmm let me understand, how do you make the search? if you add some more code to your question will be easier to help,,,